# pandas data frame error issued in the python code given below

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, quandl

```
import pandas as pd
import quandl 
df=quandl.get("WIKI/GOOGL")
df=df[['Adj.Open','Adj.High','Adj.Low','Adj.Close','Adj.Volume']]
df['HL_PCT']=(df['Adj.High']-df[Adj.Close])/df[Adj.Close]*100`
df['DL_PCT']=(df['Adj.Close']-df[Adj.Open])/df[Adj.Open]*100
df=df[['Adj.Close','HL_PCT','DL_PCT','Adj.Volume']]
print (df.head())
```

#this the python code  i tried to run in my pc but it thowrserro but i don't figure out that
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvKsh.png) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:/Users/user/Desktop/projetcs/machine learning/mc1.py", line 4, in 
df=df[['Adj.Open','Adj.High','Adj.Low','Adj.Close','Adj.Volume']]
File "C:\Users\user\python11\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2908, in **getitem**
indexer = self.loc._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis=1, raise_missing=True)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvKsh.png)
File "C:\Users\user\python11\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1254, in _get_listlike_indexer
self._validate_read_indexer(keyarr, indexer, axis, raise_missing=raise_missing)
File "C:\Users\user\python11\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1298, in _validate_read_indexer
raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
KeyError: "None of [Index(['Adj.Open', 'Adj.High', 'Adj.Low', 'Adj.Close', 'Adj.Volume'],dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"[dataset image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xk1LG.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure from the image you provided but it seems that your column names are with a space, i.e. 'Adj. Volume'